# Error: (#3501) User is already associated to the object type, article, on a unique action type Like. Original Action ID: 10202808015141547

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

copy pasted the exact code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started/ , changed the appid. Yesterday it used to work..now..not so much.any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the settings for your Open Graph action.

Go to the **Open Graph Dashboard** for your app on Facebook Developers.

Click on the **Read action**.

Click the **Advanced link**.
Make sure that **Allow Multiple** is selected for the setting called Unique action.