# Facebook Share Error: User is already associated to the object type

Tags: facebook

When I try to share same content twice I get following Error

```
User is already associated to the object type, website, on a unique action type Like. Original Action ID: 1394xxxxxx....
```

Can someone please help me with this?

I already referred this link - 
[Error: (#3501) User is already associated to the object type, article, on a unique action type Like. Original Action ID: 10202808015141547](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458739/error-3501-user-is-already-associated-to-the-object-type-article-on-a-uniq)
but did not find the steps mentioned there(settings of Open Graph action)

Comment: You're not giving enough information for people to determine why you're getting this message. Please include the website you're trying to share, the code you've implemented, og tags that might be involved, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please post the code you are using when sharing the content?

Form what I understand from this, it's all correct:

- You are "sharing" an action twice, as you mention,
- The "sharing" is probably actually a Like,
- Objects can only be Liked *once* by an User,
- The error message also refers to the Like as an unique action type,

To fix this, you have to either:

- Check your code that you are actually *sharing* something, and not liking,
- Even with sharing, FB will check if you did not recently shared it. If you do so, it might be spamming or an error on your side,
- If you want an other Open Graph action then Liking, create them and make them non-unqiue.

The above is all derived from the context. If this sound incorrect to you, please post the *exact* code you use for sharing.